# Merkle signature + PRNG?

Tags: signature, post-quantum-cryptography

In the section 3 (page 44) of the book ["Post Quantum Cryptography"](http://www.e-reading-lib.com/bookreader.php/135832/Post_Quantum_Cryptography.pdf), it says:

> Then each one-time signature key must be generated twice, once for the MSS public key generation and once during the signing phase.

Also defined $\text{PRNG}$: $\text{Seed}_{\text{in}} \rightarrow (RAND, SEED_{\text{out}})$, where $\text{RAND}$ is a random number.

Finally, it describes an example of MSS + W-OTS. Here, $\text{SEEDOTS}_j$ is used to generate signature key $X_j = (x_{t-1},...,x_0)$ where $x_i$ are generated on $(x_i, \text{SEEDOTS}_j)=PRNG(\text{SEEDOTS}_j)$.

My question: How is possible generate  the same key for public key generation and during the signing phase, for each one-time signature key, if $x_i$ is random (by definition of $\text{PRNG}$)?

Comment: Your post doesn't have the $\$$ symbols, and I can't quite tell where they should be. $\hspace{1.05 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer I edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's possible because they are using a deterministic pseudorandom random number generator (PRNG) to generate these values, as a deterministic function of some seed, which is remembered by the holder of the private key.